# Replace a cell value with the cell's axis label where it passes condition

Tags: pandas

How do I go from this...

[image]

... to this?

[image]

... or better yet, this:

`[0.92, 0.56, 0.35, 0.56, 0.35, ...]`

*There is only one Truth value per column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mul` with `mask`

```
df.mask(df,df.mul(df.index.to_series(),0))
Out[747]: 
          0      1      2
10       10  False  False
100   False  False    100
1000  False   1000  False
```

---

If want the list output

```
df.dot(df.index).tolist()
Out[749]: [10, 1000, 100]
```

---

Data input

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'0':[1,0,0],'1':[0,0,1],'2':[0,1,0]},index=[10,100,1000]).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Excellent. And Thank you for the `.dot` tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Using Wen's set up,

```
df.where(~df, df.index)

        0       1       2
10      10      False   False
100     False   False   100
1000    False   1000    False
```

Comment: For some reason this code returned `ValueError: other must be the same shape as self when an ndarray`... perhaps due to the difference of using 1/0 instead of True/False... I'm not really sure